# Symfony Doctrine entities & repository as git submodule

Tags: php, git, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

I just wonder what is your opinion about it, I have "issue" in many of my projects, when I have 1 database but multiple symfony projects on it, for example lets say I have system like gmail:

1. Project A is the Rest API for the client UI
2. Project B is the whole emailing system sending/receiving system

**PLEASE, its just an example!**

Now currently for symfony I will need to generate entities and repository for all the projects, and when I add new column I will also need to update all the projects (it can also be 3-4-5 projects etc..)

Now the first think I tought about making all the entities and repository classes a git sub-module as symfony bundle which I can update once and it will update all projects

What do you think? Is anyone handled it in other ways?

Comment: If your Project A is a REST API, why not to use this API from other projects?

Comment: This is exactly what bundles and composer are for. See [Symfony Docs: Best Practices for Reusable Bundles](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html)